# Inconsistent Objective Value when solving NLP

Tags: optimization, gekko

The objective is a quadratic function.

```
final = np.zeros_like(m.time)
final[-1] = 1
final = m.Param(final)

final_obj = ((m.Cs_n_avg[0]*final-0.0226981-0.25)*100)**2
m.Obj(final_obj)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.options.SOLVER = 3
m.options.MAX_ITER = 500
m.solve(disp=True)


m.options.OBJ
3718.2126872

m.Cs_n_avg[0]
[0.0226981, 0.059400736803, 0.093924942354, 0.13029876847, 0.17044062163, 0.21694119575, 0.27269809999]
```

If plug in the value of m.Cs_n_avg[0] into the objective function, the value is 0.

Comment: It seems to be a steady-state problem. You may want to try 'IMODE=3' instead. And, could you please include the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a related problem (see Problem 1b) from the [Dynamic Optimization course](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DynamicOptimizationBenchmarks) where the final value is minimized. The current question is incomplete because the code is missing several dependencies. Please update the question or else use the following as an example to help.

[image: dynamic optimization]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

m = GEKKO()

nt = 101
m.time = np.linspace(0,1,nt)

# Variables
x1 = m.Var(value=1)
x2 = m.Var(value=0)
u = m.Var(value=-0.48)

p = np.zeros(nt)
p[-1] = 1.0
final = m.Param(value=p)

# Equations
m.Equation(x1.dt()==u)
m.Equation(x2.dt()==x1**2 + u**2)
m.Equation(final*(x1-1)==0)

# Objective Function
m.Minimize(x2*final)

m.options.IMODE = 6
m.solve()

plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(m.time,x1.value,'k:',lw=2,label=r'$x_1$')
plt.plot(m.time,x2.value,'b-',lw=2,label=r'$x_2$')
plt.plot(m.time,u.value,'r--',lw=2,label=r'$u$')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Value')
plt.show()
```